# How to add custom post type category?

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

I am working on wordpress, everything is going fine, but i have to create custom post type named services, and i just created. But i have to create it's category too that's why i just write following code:

```
function services_init() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => 'Services',
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
    );
    register_post_type('Services', $args);
}
```

Now problem is that it shows all category of post too. I don't like to show to those category. I just want to create new for my Services post type. 
Any help please ?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: hi i think its best way to do by plugin or if you want to do by code i suggest  to read this 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

or you can try this site for build taxonomy and post type

http://generatewp.com/post-type/

http://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

and when you are creating post type write name of category which you are going to create through taxonomy for select that taxonomy for post type

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies (like categories) can be used by multiple post types. If you want a separate taxonomy just for your custom post type, you'll have to create your own:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Use the [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Example) in the documentation to create a "Service Category" taxonomy and then pass the slug for that taxonomy in the `taxonomies` argument when registering your post type:

```
function services_init() {
$args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label' => 'Services',
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => array('service-category')
    );
    register_post_type('Services', $args);
}
```

Assuming the slug for your custom taxonomy is `service-category`.